# Phonegap navigator.camera.getPicture memory warning

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Each time I use the phonegap API function to create an image on iOS, after I click on *Use photo* I get a warning. *(The memory usage spikes to roughly 60MB)*

**My code:**

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20 });

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    console.log('succ');
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

**Warning:**

```
2014-05-17 10:56:35.122 Cityfe[1845:60b] Received memory warning.
2014-05-17 10:56:35.195 Cityfe[1845:60b] succ
```

Is this something to be worried about?

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```
function getPhoto(source) {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 30,
        targetWidth: 600,
        targetHeight: 600,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        correctOrientation: true,
        sourceType: source
    });
}

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    console.log('succ');
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```